# Not able to get auto-suggestion in eclipse for Google Map API v2 methods

Tags: android, eclipse

Eclipse is not giving auto suggestion for methods of "Google Map API V2". I mean if i hover over the method, it didn't tells about that element...but it says **This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.**

I could not able to find solution on internet and in stackoverflow.
Help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path of a javadoc will be provided in the jar file itself for you android jar file it will be in the jar file so the eclipse will be able to find the source and shows you the method description or so, but for Google map API v2 google hasn't provided and such docs so you have to refer to the Web for the documentation

Comment: Same thing i have noticed...i went to: project's Java Build Path and when expanded "Android Dependencies jar files" i found JavaDoc Location:(None).....But i didn't know that Google has not provided this...i was assuming may be my Jar file is broken. Thanxx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the *Javadoc* location for your library into the following location:

```
Referenced Libraries > right click on your .jar > Javadoc Location
```